# jquery animation repeat, what is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please evaluate my code and let me know if it is correct.

I am trying to run one animation after another, pause for 5000 milliseconds, reset all heights back to zero and repeat the animation again indefinitely.

```
function animateThis(){
            $(".bars div:nth-child(1)").animate({'height':'49px'}, 2000, function() {
                $(".bars div:nth-child(2)").animate({'height':'112px'}, 2000, function() {
                    $(".bars div:nth-child(3)").animate({'height':'174px'}, 2000, function() {
                        $(".bars div:nth-child(4)").animate({'height':'236px'}, 2000, function() {
                            $(".bars div:nth-child(5)").animate({'height':'298px'}, 2000, function() {              
                                $('.bars div').delay(2000).css({"height" : "0"}), function() { animateThis()};
                            });
                        });
                    });                                                          
                });
            });
        }
    $(".bars").ready(function(){animateThis()});
```

The example can be seen at http://execusite.com/fazio/files/careers-banner/test.html

I have reformatted it from some answers I have received yesterday but it still doesn't work and I haven't received any feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: So you've described the code and the expected behaviour. What is the actual behaviour?

Comment: @Karl the actual behavior can be seen at the link. I will explain.

Each height animation fires in succession as it should. However, the .delay before changing the height to zero does not work and the entire function is not repeating. So once the fifth bar animates, it immediately returns them all to 0 and stops.

Comment: @JJ Why do you use `$(".bars").ready()`?

Comment: @Sime, that's a good question... I had a coworker help me write this and he added that, from what I understand it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks everyone, all you guys have been super helpful. I love Stack Overflow, hope you don't mine dealing with a JavaScript noob like me. :)

Comment: @JJ Well, I see myself as a JavaScript evangelist so this is part of my job :)

Comment: @JJ `$(document).ready()` is used to make sure that the page has loaded when the code executes http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Sime, thankfully I do understand that concept and it is in my final code. Do you have any good recommendations for learning jQuery? I have Sitepoint's Novice to Ninja but I am only half way through

Comment: @JJ jQuery is fairly simple. You have around 140 methods that you can use on so-called jQuery objects which are constructed using the $() function. You just have to go trough the documentation and learn about each method to understand it. It takes time but is necessary in order to have an overview over the capabilities of jQuery. Once to learn about each method, you should be fine. If you need info about a particular method, you just google for it like so: "jquery method-name" (for example "jquery ready").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/T5acF/4/

```
function animateThis() {
    var length = $('.bars div').stop().each(function(i, val) {
        $(val).delay(i * 2000).animate({ height: (i * 62) + 49 }, 2000, function() {
            if (i === (length - 1)) {
                $('.bars div').animate({ height: 0 }, 2000, animateThis);
            }
        });
    }).length;
}

$(document).ready(function() { animateThis(); });
```

---

**EDIT:** Didn't notice the animation back to `0`. Fixed with this updated version.

**EDIT:** Adding `.stop()` before the new `.each()` seemed to clean up the issue I was having.

**EDIT:** Made it a little more efficient by replacing `$(this).index()` with `i` (which represents the same index).

---

I'm obviously not paying close enough attention. You didn't want to animate the height back to `0`, but rather wanted to delay 5000 milliseconds, then immediately reset.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/T5acF/5/

```
function animateThis() {
    var length = $('.bars div').each(function(i, val) {
        $(val).delay(i * 2000).animate({ height: (i * 62) + 49 }, 2000, function() {
            if (i === (length - 1)) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                     $('.bars div').height(0);
                     animateThis();
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }).length;
}

$(document).ready(function() { animateThis(); });
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That seems a better way to write it as well. Much appreciated! I will work to add the delay to this.

Comment: There's an issue with it that I need to find, but I need to break away for a few minutes. If someone else finds it, you should accept their answer since I can't look right this minute.

Comment: @Patrick, Sime has an acceptable version as well so no worries. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Patrick I do notice that on the 2nd or third time around, the animations becomes out of sync.

Comment: @JJ Nold - Yes, that was the issue. I seem to have fixed it with a call to `.stop()` before the new series of animations begins.

Comment: @JJ Nold - Sorry, I'm not paying close enough attention. You didn't want to animate them back to `0`, but rather wanted a 5 second delay. I added another solution that accomplishes this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function animateThis() {
    var divs = $(".bars div").get();
    var time = 2000;
    $(divs[0]).animate({'height': '49px'}, time, function() {
        $(divs[1]).animate({'height': '112px'}, time, function() {
            $(divs[2]).animate({'height': '174px'}, time, function() {
                $(divs[3]).animate({'height': '236px'}, time, function() {
                    $(divs[4]).animate({'height': '298px'}, time, function() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $(divs).css('height', '0px');
                            animateThis();
                        }, time);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

***Note:*** This code is redundant. I wrote this just to show how to make the code more efficient (by getting rid of unnecessary selector queries). I would go with patrick's answer if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var animateThis = function(){
            $(".bars div:nth-child(1)").animate({'height':'49px'}, 2000, function() {
                $(".bars div:nth-child(2)").animate({'height':'112px'}, 2000, function() {
                    $(".bars div:nth-child(3)").animate({'height':'174px'}, 2000, function() {
                        $(".bars div:nth-child(4)").animate({'height':'236px'}, 2000, function() {
                            $(".bars div:nth-child(5)").animate({'height':'298px'}, 2000, function() {              
                                $('.bars div').delay(2000).animate({"height" : "0"}, 0), function() { animateThis()};
                            });
                        });
                    });                                                          
                });
            });
        };
    $(".bars").ready(function(){animateThis()});
```

Comment: Svinto, thanks. Now the delay is working. However, it's still not repeating.

Answer (score 0):

<s>`delay(2000).css({"height" : "0"})`</s>

Here, you haven't specified a callback for what to do after the delay; the `.css` call runs immediately because `.delay` returns immediately (and would set up the callback, if one were provided, to run later).

`.css()` makes an immediate change, not an animated one. There is still a delay before the change, but you might easily get confused about that, since the previous transition does animate. It seems like you intend for the div to snap back into place, but you need to account for the time taken by the previous transition. As is, you're only just waiting for the previous transition to finish before snapping into place.

`, function() { animateThis() };`

Here, you define an un-named callback function that calls animateThis(), but you don't actually call it - you haven't provided it to a function (such as <s>delay</s> <s>css</s> `animate`) that takes a callback. Even though we don't actually want to animate the last transition, using `animate` instead of `css` lets us hook in a callback.

<s>Stephen provided the fix in his answer.</s> Try this:

```
$('.bars div').delay(4000).animate({"height": 0}, 0, function() { animateThis(); })
```

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, and your diagnosis of the problem is correct, but my solution was wrong.

Comment: @Stephen: Blarg. It certainly **looked** right to me, but by now I've probably fallen afoul of more Javascript gotchas than I've written working lines of code in Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it using correct *looking* callback syntax, but `.delay()` doesn't accept callbacks as the second parameter.  The second parameter seems to be some queue name string.

Comment: Hmm. A bit of Googling suggests that I haven't really got the diagnosis right; `.delay(2000)` without a second argument is supposed to delay the "default queue", and as far as I can tell, the effect of method chaining is to push effects onto that queue. jQuery is even deeper magic than I thought :)